# Using JavaFX API on IKVM

Tags: .net, javafx, java, ikvm

Is is possible to use JavaFX on IKVM? Say you compile the `jfxrt.jar` or get the sources for JavaFX from the OpenJDK project and compile them. I have tried a few things on my own but without success.

Comment: What's your use case for IKVM? Is it to bring JavaFX on iOS. Then you'd better look at robovm

Comment: Perhaps just to package a java app as a native Windows app, I can see the use for it. Deployment of Java VMs to consumers is a pain

Comment: I'm now looking at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/selfContainedApps/index.html

Comment: @ZiglioNZ I think this is more about how to create an installable package. I was wondering if I could use JavaFX as cross-platform GUI toolkit.

Comment: So far I have made it up until one error `Graphics Device initialization failed for :  d3d, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found`

I have compiled both jfxrt.jar and my sample JavaFX app to dll with `ikvmc`

Comment: @ax1mx2 I'm in love with DukeScript, currently building for Linux and Windows, could run on Mac, Android and iPhone (webview + java) https://dukescript.com/ https://github.com/goGPS-Project/goGPS_FX